# My program won't print out correct math numbers

Tags: pascal

I'm coding a little program but it won't print out the right math answer, it just stays at 993.
The Code:

```pascal
program _Gul_;
uses crt;
var a: integer;
var b: integer;
begin
  writeln('1000 - 7?');
  a := 1000;
  b := a - 7;
  while a > 0 do
  begin
    writeln (a - 7, ' - 7?');
    delay(120);
    a := a - 7;
    writeln (b)
    if a = 6 then
      break;
  end;
  writeln('я гуль')
 end
```

I don't quite know why it is not working. I defined "b" and made a command that prints it out and the output is just:

[image: This]

Comment: Just before the while loop, you assign `b := a - 7;` which makes `b` equal to 993. In the while loop you decrement `a` with 7 for each loop and it surely decreases toward 0, but you do nothing with `b` except `writeln(b)`, which prints 993. When you say "it is not working", **what should it do?**

Comment: Perhaps you should have code like `writeln(a);` instead of `writeln(b);` in the `while` loop?

Comment: I corrected the wording in your post: you said that Pascal won't printout ... Pascal does exactly what you tell it to do. If it isn't according to your expectations, look carefully at what you have told it to do :)

Answer (score 1):

You never update the value in `b`. In point of fact, `b` is not necessary to your program at all. Your printing strategy is also more complicated than it needs to be. Print `a` minus `7`, then do the subtraction and print it. This prevents the program telling you the rest of `6 - 7` is `6`.

```
program _Gul_;
uses 
  crt;

var 
  a: integer;

begin
  a := 1000;

  while a > 0 do
  begin
    writeln (a, ' - 7?');
    delay(120);
    a := a - 7;
    writeln (a);

    if a = 6 then
      break;
  end;

  writeln('я гуль')

 end.
```